# Ему вручили на праздник День нефтяника (или - на праздник Дня нефтяника?) грамоту

Tags: согласование

В ответ на вопрос о согласовании здесь на сайте был такой ответ:

Праздник называется Рождество Христово. Но поздравляют обычно так: с праздником (каким?) Рождества Христова. Форма Р.п. является несогласованным определением.

В других случаях возможны варианты (в том числе "приложение + название в И.п.").

Вопрос такой: как согласовать слово "праздник" с определением "День нефтяника" в следующем предложении:

Ему вручили на праздник День нефтяника (или - на праздник Дня нефтяника) грамоту.

Answer (score 2):

*С праздником (каким? чего?) Рождества Христова* - это корректно, несогласованное определение, когда определяемое слово управляет родительным падежом (праздник Рождества).

*На праздник Дня нефтяника* - некорректно (на праздник (какой? чего?)дня). Праздник дня - это когда день что-то празднует в противоположность торжеству ночи.

Корректно: *Ему вручили на праздник (какой?) День нефтяника* - название праздника - слитное сочетание, несогласованное определение.

Возможно оформить как согласованное определение, но тогда оно будет обособленным со значением пояснения: *Это случилось во время праздника - Дня нефтяника.*

Или заменить слово праздник отглагольным существительным празднование: *На праздновании (чего?) Дня нефтяника.*

А ещё проще - обойтись без родового слова:*Ему вручили (когда?) на День нефтяника*.